# How to plot multiple Y-axes keeping the same X-axes using python plotly?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I tried to do it using `add_trace` method as shown below:

```py
figure = go.Figure()

for i in variables:
    figure.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=records["time"],
                                y=records[i],
                                yaxis="y"))
```

Here, the yaxis value should change for each value in the loop... like y1, y2, y3 and so on as different y axis variable should have different value for yaxis. Is there a way to achieve this ?
Or is there a different way to plot multiple y-axes dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want the Yaxis tilte to display as 'y1' 'y2' etc, then you can do:

```
for i in variables:
    figure.add_trace(
       go.Scatter(
         x=records["time"],
         y=records[i],
         yaxis="y"+str(i),
       ),
    )
```

Else, if it is from a list of y values then you can do something like:

```
yaxis_titles = ['State', 'Country', 'Continent']
for i in variables:
    figure.add_trace(
       go.Scatter(
         x=records["time"],
         y=records[i],
         yaxis=yaxis_titles[i],
       ),
    )
```

Comment: The "variables" content is the value that i want to plot on the Y-axes. So, i'm running a for loop "i" to plot all the contents of "variables" on the same y-axes... But to make this plot successful, the y-axis attribute in the add_trace function should also be updated for every loop such as y1, y2, y3 .... So, my question is, is there a way to do this y-axis attribute update ?

Comment: I think multiple yaxis in plotly should help you.  https://plotly.com/python/multiple-axes/